# Option to change HTTP method

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to call an ESRI feature service with a long URL using the ESRIJSON driver, an error appeared from the GIS server

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""[http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd%22%3E)
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Request URL Too Long</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Request URL Too Long</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I find out that I must change my request from `GET` to `POST`

from `ogr2ogr` How do I change my request from `GET` to `POST` ?